# using custom var to referance a table row by id in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

new to php. problem implementing code that works (on my wamp server with regular php pages) in wordpress:
mind you im doing all the following in a wordpress page with php enabled by insert-php plugin.
on first page, i managed to get access to my custom table `projects` and display it and the list of projects properly and it works:

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( " SELECT * FROM  nbm_projects ORDER BY id ASC" );
foreach($result as $row) {
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'. $row->project_name . '</td>';
echo '<td>'. $row->project_liner . '</td>';
echo '<td>'. $row->actor_name . '</td>';
echo '<td width=325>';
echo '<a class="btn" href="http://www.mysite.com/read/?id='.$row->id.'">Read</a>';
```

when user presses the 'read' link i want to direct them to a page called "read" that displays the specific project. so im appending `?id='.$row->id` to the read url

here come the issues in read page im managing to get the var from the url using REQUEST:

```
$id = null;
if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];    }

if ( null==$id ) {
    header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/db-display/"); **(url of the first page)**
```

now i want to use the id to pull from my table which has an id column the specific project data

the following works outside of wordpress but is not working inside:

```
global $wpdb;
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
// $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects where id = ?"; **this is vanilla version**
$sql = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM projects where id = ?"); **this is for wordpress**
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($id));
$data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

allowing me to pull data from specific area of table with `$data['project_name']`..
what am i doing worng for it to work in wordpress?

Comment: Do not use insert-php plugin or similar. Create a custom page template, post type, shortcode or widget instead

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
$sql = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM projects where id = ?");
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
```

`$wpdb->get_results()` already returns a set of results or `NULL`, so when you prepare the query you are not passing a real query, but a set of results.
You should either use `$wpdb` or `PDO`. Being on wordpress I would choose wordpress style.  More info on `$wpdb` [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)